# How can I fit the randon effect in the gamm (or gamm4) in r?

Tags: r

I would like to know if my response variable (y) is significantly affected by a categorical variable ("x"), with two discrete values ("high" and "low").

This response value "y" has spatial autocorrelation, which are numerical spatial eigenvector, named as "MEM2" and "MEM5". I'm trying to fix these spatial eigenvectors into the function using a `gamm4`. But I don't know where I fit them into the formula.

I've made by two ways:

(1) First:

```
m2 <- gamm(y ~ x, random=list(MEM2=~1, MEM5=~1), family=poisson )

summary(m2)

summary(m2$gam)
```

The output

```
Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
y ~ x

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.4574     0.2029   2.254   0.0300 *
xbaixa       -0.6330     0.3338  -1.897   0.0655 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


R-sq.(adj) =  0.0625   
  Scale est. = 1         n = 40
```

(2) Second:

```
m2 <- gamm(y ~ x +s(MEM2) + s(MEM5),
           random=list(MEM2=~1, MEM5=~1), family=poisson )

summary(m2)

summary(m2$gam)
```

The output:

```
Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
y ~ x + s(MEM2) + s(MEM5)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.3434     0.2275   1.509    0.140
xbaixa       -0.4438     0.3689  -1.203    0.237

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value
s(MEM2)   1      1 1.343   0.254
s(MEM5)   1      1 0.994   0.325

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0567   
  Scale est. = 1         n = 40
```

Anyone knows if it's right? And which I should use?